# Python script has command calling two scripts. How to kill both scripts if one is finished and rerun the command?

Tags: python

I am making a project in Ubuntu, which has a login and registration. This script will call both scripts where one script is used for login and one is used for registration. They need to run simultaneously. Whenever someone makes a login or registration, the login or registration script ends. What can I do in this simple script to kill the command (killing the other script too) and make it recall the entire command of running the two scripts if at least one of them ends? I want to be able to leave this script running without having to run the script manually.

```
import os

os.system('python3 testdb2.py & python3 testdb2_register.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use fork and then spwan 2 process and you know PID 
you can do whatever you want to do with those process as per intended logic

`os.fork()`